# How to Display available locations in a table powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-4.0, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Hi I use the PowerShell command `Get-AzureRmLocation` to list the available locations from azure. I want to display them neatly in a table or some well formatted manner instead of listing them line by line.

I tried

```
$locations = @(Get-AzureRmLocation | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Available Locations :" 
$locations | Format-Table
```

But that also listing everything which makes the screen look long and not so good. is there a way?

I am getting the output as a list like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsqzu.jpg

I want it to be a two table column with all available locations something like that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to following example:

```
$locations = Get-AzureRmLocation

$locations | Format-Table -Property Location,DisplayName
```

I test in my lab, I get like below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks , for the help. this is not what i wanted. but it looks better than what i have now

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
$locations = Get-AzureRmLocation
$locations | Format-Table @{n="Available Locations";e={$_.DisplayName}}
```

Comment: Nope brother , it still shows it as list of items. can i have it like two sided table ?

Comment: This should be a table with one column. I don't have access to Azure, so you need to update your question with the output you get from this and an example of what the output should look like. Remember to replace sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

To list all Azure locations I would suggest using the [Get-AzLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azlocation?view=azps-5.7.0)

```
Get-AzLocation | Format-Table -Property Location, DisplayName
```

**Result:**
[image: Get-AzLocation command output example]

**PowerShell version:**
[image: PowerShell version]